# how to use simpleAdapter for custom checkbox in ListView android?

Tags: android, listview

Iam using ArrayAdapter for ListView.Each ListItems contains checkbox,Title,TitleInfo(below title),period,Image(static/from drawable).Now i want to develop this code into simple adapter.How to use simple adapter for checkboxes and how to handle checkbox events in this simpleAdapter?

Regards,
Android developer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do that with SimpleAdapter. 
You'll have to create your own custom ListView items as described in [this tutorial](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)